# Trying to get the users location on location changed is unreliable

Tags: java, android, location

so i have been trying to get the users location, at first I was using a library called simple location to make my life easier. Until I realised some of my users locations were returning stale.

I could very clearly see that the user was in one location, but the location I was sending was back when the originally opened the app.

I have since started trying to get the location natively but I am not having much luck. When I am listening for changes, it can sometimes refuse to update unless I move, which isnt good as I need to get the users location if they're still.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    public static String lat = "";
    public static String lng = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Button", "Pressed");
                textView.setText("Latitude: " + lat + "  Longitude: " + lng);
        }
        });


        locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MainActivity();


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0, locationListener);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10, 0, locationListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configureLocation();
                return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d("Lat", "lat"+location.getLatitude());
        Log.d("Lng", "lng"+location.getLongitude());

        lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        lng = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    public void configureLocation(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
            }
            return;
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 1000, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }


}
```

This is the test app that I am using. Is there a way for as soon as the application opens that it will then give me an up to date report of where the user is?

Comment: Try to use actual location api, it called FusedLocationProviderClient. You can find a lot of examples.